# Filtering Content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create a filterable photo gallery using jQuery and multiple classes. I have some code set up, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody give me any insight on how to fix this function?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sorter a').click(function(e){
        var sortName = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
        if(sortName === 'all-images'){
        $('#photorow1 li').show().removeClass('hidden');
          } 
        else {
   $('#photorow1 li').filter(sortName).show().removeClass('hidden')
               .end().not(sortName).hide().addClass('hidden');
         }
e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

*updated code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're doing a `return false` before any work is being done, move that to the end of your click handler :)

Overall you can clean it up a bit, something like this should do:

```
$(function(){
  $('#sorter a').click(function(e){
    var sortName = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
    if(sortName === 'all-images') {
       $('#photorow1 li').show();
    } else {
       $('#photorow1 li').filter(filterVal).show().removeClass('hidden')
                   .end().not(filterVal).hide().addClass('hidden');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I recommend that you just add `display: none;` to the `.hidden` CSS rules (if you need that class for something else), otherwise just [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)/[`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) works.

Comment: This is working, but it is hiding all the elements and somehow overlooking the elements with the class name that I tried to specify using sortName...if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `return false;` should be at the end of the function, because any code that comes after it in that function will be ignored.

Plus, you don't need that and `e.preventDefault();` in the same function, they overlap a bit. You can read more about their similarities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false/1357151#1357151). Pick one.

Comment: Be careful with your last statement, they don't do the *same thing*, even your linked answer accurately distinguishes the two :)

Comment: Yes, that sentence could have been worded better.